# Minikube single node cluster architecture

Tags: kubernetes, serverless, minikube, faas

I am confused as to how the minikube single node cluster works, when I start a k8s cluster using `minikube start --driver=docker`, is the single node itself a docker container, or it is our local machine? I assume that single node is the local machine and the pods are containers inside this node.

Can anyone confirm this? Or perhaps correct me?

I have tried looking into the explanations in the minikube docs, but could not find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last two paragraphs of [kubernetes-basics/Using Minikube to Create a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/create-cluster/cluster-intro/), it says:

> `Minikube` is a lightweight Kubernetes implementation that creates **a VM on your local machine** and deploys a simple cluster containing only one node.

**Minikube** creates a single node cluster contained in **a virtual machine (VM)**, with the help of a virtualization manager on Linux, MacOS, or Windows operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Minikube cluster is a single-node cluster, meaning that it consists of only one machine–typically a containerized or virtual machine running on our laptop or desktop and deploys a simple cluster containing only one node.

Nodes in Kubernetes clusters are assigned roles. Start your Minikube cluster and then run the following command:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

You should see one node, named minikube, because this is a single-node cluster.

```
NAME      STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
minikube   Ready    control-plane,master   99s     v1.23.1
```

Refer to the [blog](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/the-architecture-of-a-kubernetes-cluster/) written by Eric Gregory for information on architecture of single-node clusters.